# Check if input is int or float in range

Tags: python, windows

I want a while loop to store an input in a variable and check if it is an integer or a float before printing a statement and breaking the loop. If the variable fails the check I want it to continue back to the top of the loop and ask for the input again until it gets a valid response.

Somehow regardless of what the input is, the loop asks for an input again and seems to skip the if conditional block.

```
def FeelingCalc():

    Monday = 0

    while Monday == 0:
        Monday = input("On a scale of 1 to 10, how did you feel on Monday? ")
        if isinstance(Monday,(int,float)) and 11 > float(Monday) > 0:
            print("Alright. Let's move on.")
            break
        else:
            print("Please type a whole number between 1 and 10.")
            Monday = 0
            continue
```

I have tried different solutions for the if conditional like:

```
if Monday != type(int)
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything either. It still goes to the else block.

Comment: The variable `Monday` will always be a string. That is what `input()` *always* returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
if isinstance(Monday,(int,float)) and 11 > float(Monday) > 0:
```

Since `Monday` is derived from `input()` it will always be a string.  If it *wasn't* a string, but an int or float, there would be no need to cast it to float.  You probably want something like this:

```py
try:
    x = float(input())
except:
    print("Please enter a number ")

if x > 11 or x < 0:
    print("Number must be in range 1-10")
```

**EDIT** if you don't want anything except `int` (as the other answers assume), replace `float` with `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You always get string when you use `input`. So, you have to convert `Monday` to an integer or float.

```
Monday = int(input("On a scale of 1 to 10, how did you feel on Monday? "))
```

**EDIT**

You might want to use `try` block:

```
try:
   Monday = float(input("On a scale of 1 to 10, how did you feel on Monday?"))
except: 
   Monday = 0
```